# Uploading then renaming multiple files over ssh

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh, os.system

I have a python script which is testing a processing server. The files that are uploaded are renamed when the upload is done to indicate that they're ready to be processed. To test a heavy load I've made the script multithreaded but when I watch the upload directory on the server only one file comes in at a time. Here is the relevant code:

```
def worker(queue):
    while queue.qsize():
        try:
            infile, filename = queue.get()
        except Queue.Empty:
            return

        size = os.path.getsize(infile)

        copyStart = time.time()

        print '{}: {} started'.format(time.asctime(), filename)

        os.system('ssh servername "cat > {0} && mv {0} {1}" < {2}'.format(filename, filename.replace('upl', 'jpg'), infile))

        print '{}: {} took {} secs for {} bytes'.format(time.asctime(), filename, time.time() - copyStart, size)

q = Queue.Queue()

for media_type, num in config.get("media").items():
    media_dir = media_dir_format.format(media_type)
    print '\nLoading media from ' + media_dir
    itemId = startId

    for i in range(num):
        infile = media_dir + random.choice([x for x in os.listdir(media_dir) if x[-3:].lower() == 'jpg'])

        filename = output_format.format(itemId, media_type[:-1])

        q.put((infile, filename))


        itemId += 1

threads = []

for i in range(config.get("threads")):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(q, ))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
```

So basically I fill a queue with a mapping between randomly chosen input files and well formatted output names then start however many threads are specified in the test config file. The issue is even though the `os.system` calls are executed at similar times, the uploads only happen one after another, as can be seen from the script output:

```
Fri Jul 11 17:06:44 2014: /bla/foo/b1.upl started
Fri Jul 11 17:06:44 2014: /blah/foo/b2.upl started
Fri Jul 11 17:06:44 2014: /blah/foo/b3.upl started
Fri Jul 11 17:07:03 2014: /blah/foo/b1.upl took 19.0852029324 secs for 8947009 bytes
Fri Jul 11 17:07:03 2014: /blah/foo/b4.upl started
Fri Jul 11 17:07:21 2014: /blah/foo/b3.upl took 36.8071010113 secs for 8348547 bytes
Fri Jul 11 17:07:21 2014: /blah/foo/b5.upl started
Fri Jul 11 17:07:40 2014: /blah/foo/b2.upl took 55.855271101 secs for 8348547 bytes
```

That's just a bit of it but you can see that consecutive uploads take longer and longer. I find it hard to believe this is an `ssh` problem as I can have ssh into multiple shells at once without a problem and a little searching has shown plenty of examples of people using `os.system` in multiple threads at once so where's the bottleneck?

Comment: You could explain it with a slow uplink speed. All 3 files start in parallel - one gets done faster for whatever reason but immediately starts another upload, still consuming bandwidth. Retry with just 3 files and see if those other numbers improve.

Comment: I got a similar experience with only three files being uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be an underlying problem with `os.system`. Replacing that usage with the newer [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) worked as expected, as long as **shell is true**:

```
subprocess.call(
    'ssh servername "cat > {0} && mv {0} {1}" < {2}'.format(
        filename, 
        filename.replace('upl', 'jpg'),
        infile
    ),
    shell=True
)
```